# What are Modules in VB.NET and what are its advantages?

Tags: vb.net

I have been new to Visual Basic. Why exactly do we use a module in VB.NET?

What would be a small example of a module and calling it one of the form?

Comment: Short answer - don't use modules in VB.NET. Especially because you are new, don't get into bad habits. :) There is a good use though - Extensions. Other than that - use shared classes.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @Neolisk i disagree with that assertion. Modules have a purpose in VB.net and using them for that purpose is 100% acceptable.  Certain features simply can't be used without them.  A blanket assertion that they are bad is wrong.

Comment: @JaredPar: In my experience, they are more "bad" than "good". Which features beside Extensions do you mean? To elaborate, I've seen people doing complete chaos in the project, just because they think modules are okay to use. It's like "okay to carry a loaded gun with you at all times".

Comment: @Neolisk extension methods, declarative non-OO code, project level members / data

Comment: Declarative non-OO code is what? For project level members and data, there are shared classes, even though doing it so has repercussions, and becomes a maintenance nightmare at a certain point. But using modules becomes a nightmare much sooner. C# devs somehow manage without modules, right? :)

Comment: I wonder what transpired the decision to use static classes for writing extensions in C#, but keep them in modules in VB.NET. VB.NET could have also used shared classes, to keep consistent, then modules would become obsolete. If anybody knows the full story, please share your thoughts.

Comment: @Neolisk i think your assertion that modules lead to chaos is completely unfounded.  There is 0 difference between a class with all static members and a module.  The primary difference is whether or not the members need a qualifier.

Comment: @JaredPar: This a huge difference, believe me. Anything global is bad in code. The more local it is, the easier it is to maintain, but I think we are getting off-topic with this. :)

Comment: @Neolisk as I already said there no difference between modules and static classes.  Your assertion that one is fine and the other is broken is simply incorrect.  There is a small difference in name resolution only, it has no affect on global data

Answer (score 6):

A `Module` in VB.Net is essentially a grouping a methods and fields.  These members can be accessed without qualification anywhere that the module itself is accessible.  This mechanism is actually how many of the standard VB operators  `ChDir`, `ChDrive`, `CurDir` are implemented.  There is a module in the VB runtime named `FileSystem` which defines all of these operations

The main advantages / differences between `Module` and `Class` are the following

- It's a declarative grouping of functions that aren't associated with instances of an object
- It's the only way to define extension methods in VB.Net
- No need for a redundant qualifier on every usage of a project helper method
- No need to protect a module from accidental instantiation by the developer.  It's by definition not creatable

Comment: +1 for `It's the only way to define extension methods in VB.Net`.

Comment: its also a good place for Sub Main